# UIScrollView on top of UIView (XIB) and scrollview will not scroll

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xib

In my xib I created a UIView.

I added a child to that UIView which was a UIScrollView. The scrollView will not scroll.

**BUT**
If I drag the UIScrollView out of the UIView so they are on the same level then it **will scroll** as expected.

So why does my scrollview stop scrolling when **it is inside a UIView on my XIB.**

Is this a bug or is there something more I need to do to get the scrollview scrolling while a child of a UIView.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: When your content size will become more than your frame size. It will allow you to scroll.

Comment: It does scroll, BUT NOT when I move it inside a UIView. Sorry if this wasnt clear from my question.

Comment: do you have tried to alloc the UIView?

Comment: if you allocate the uiview your REALLOCATING the view in memory and basically resetting everything that was done in the xib.... Xib does all that for you, set the frame, allocate, initiate, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Apple documentation on scroll views..

The scroll view must know the size of the content view so it knows when to stop scrolling; by default, it “bounces” back when scrolling exceeds the bounds of the content.

Probably, you should set it's contentSize:

```
 [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 480)];
```

Since your scrollView is a child of your view, you must set it's content size smaller than your view.

Also, don't forget to set your scroll view enabled.

```
 [scrollView setEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

set the content size for your scroll ...  `scroll.contentSize= CGSizeMake(320,2000)`.

Comment: Hmm I guess I need to rewrite the question... BECAUSE IT DOES SCROLL. The problem is that when it is moved inside of a UIView it no longer scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the container UIView has `userInteractionEnabled` property is FALSE.
This is the only reason, it will not allow you to scroll while scrollview is added to any UIView.